# How can I format a div into a fixed navigation bar on a webpage?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a pinned navigation bar that stays at the bottom of a web page and i'm wondering what the right code would be.

I tried the following;
With the "fixed" class formatted as follows in the css file and the formatting for the "button-navbar" class formatted as:

```css
div.fixed {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0; 
}
        
.button-navbar {
        background-color: white;
        border: 2px solid #ffb90f;
        width: 90px;
        height: 40px;
        color: black;
        display: table-cell;
        margin: 15px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        border-radius: 8px;
        line-height: 30px;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
        -webkit-transition: 0.4s; /*Safari*/
        transition: 0.4s;
        transition-duration: 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed">
    <a href="homepage.php" class="button-navbar">Back to dashboard</a> <br>
    <a href="IntroductionQuiz.php" class="button-navbar"> Retake Quiz</a>
</div>
```

Comment: So what is wrong?

Comment: the two buttons i've added stack up vertically instead of spreading horizontally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `<br>` and change `display: table-cell;`  to `display: inline-block;`

If you want div.fixed to be full width then you need `left: 0;`. This make buttons centered.

```css
div.fixed {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;} 

.button-navbar {
        background-color: white;
        border: 2px solid #ffb90f;
        width: 90px;
        height: 40px;
        color: black;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 15px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        border-radius: 8px;
        line-height: 30px;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
        -webkit-transition: 0.4s; /*Safari*/
        transition: 0.4s;
        transition-duration: 0.4s;
```

```html
<div class="fixed">
    <a href="homepage.php" class="button-navbar">Back to dashboard</a>
    <a href="IntroductionQuiz.php" class="button-navbar"> Retake Quiz</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I just made the changes and seemed to have fix the problem but gives rise to another one. I have a transition applied to the navbar buttons on hover but once i hover over the buttons the text in the buttons isn't centered like it was before the hover. heres the formatting for .button-navbar:hover :
`.button-navbar:hover {
 background-color: #ffb90f;
 color: white;
 width: 200px;
 height: 60px; }`